# Slow or unresponsive click event in Panels inside the FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an issue with C# trying to design a grid of panels inside a FlowLayoutPanel. The problem I have is; the click event is slow to respond and sometimes does not trigger at all. At first I thought it had something to do with TableLayoutPanel because I had placed those child Panels inside TableLayoutPanel container and were super slow. I tried to change to FlowLayoutPanel thinking that would solve the problem but didn't. Kindly assist, is it something with the for loop or something else I am missing.

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace POS
{
    public partial class frmTest : Form
    {
        public frmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
            string[] panNames = new string[] { "John", "Doe", "Alice", "Lorem", "Ipsum", "Sudo", "Append", "Concat", "Java", "C#" };
            int[] ages = new int[] { 20, 50, 25, 55, 29, 36, 47, 23, 41, 21 };

            for (int i = 0; i < panNames.Length; i++)
            {
                Panel panChild = new Panel();
                Label lblName = new Label();
                Label lblAge = new Label();
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panChild);
                flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
                panChild.Controls.Add(lblName);
                panChild.Controls.Add(lblAge);
                panChild.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                lblName.Text = panNames[i];
                lblAge.Text = "Age " + ages[i].ToString();
                lblName.Location = new Point(63, 40);
                lblAge.Location = new Point(4, 4);
                panChild.Click += (c, args) =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(lblName.Text);
                };

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

[image: Design Output][image: Code Part]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here in this snippet, but perhaps not for the reason you expect. The reason it seems to "sometimes does not trigger at all" is that if you're clicking on either of the `Label` controls you are actually *not* clicking on the panel because the child control is the target of the event. You can verify this by clicking in the "blank space" and avoiding the label rectangles which should make the message box "work every time".

```
panChild.Click += (c, args) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(lblName.Text);
};
```

---

So one inconvenient option is to subscribe a `Click` event for each and every dynamic control you create. As an alternative, it may be simpler to implement [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) on the main form and handle its `public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)` method such that it fires a notification when a click *event* (**WM_LBUTTONDOWN** *message*) occurs on *any control on any form*. You can then sort things out in one handler and determine whether the click is something you want to act upon.

[image: detecting the clicked control]

---

Heres a revised version of your code:

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        };
        flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Margin = new Padding(10),
            BackColor = Color.Azure,
            AutoScroll = true,
        };
        Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1);
        ClickAnywhere += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(sender is Control control)
            {
                var message = 
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text) ?
                        control.Name : control.Text;
                // Better to not block the click event
                // for a modal dialog so use BeginInvoke.
                BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(message));
            }
        };
    }
    FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        string[] panNames = { "John", "Doe", "Alice", "Lorem", "Ipsum", "Sudo", "Append", "Concat", "Java", "C#" };
        int[] ages = { 20, 50, 25, 55, 29, 36, 47, 23, 41, 21 };

        for (int i = 0; i < panNames.Length; i++)
        {
            Panel panChild = new Panel
            { 
                Name = $"{nameof(panChild)}{i}",
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                BackColor = Color.White,
            };
            Label lblAge = new Label { Name = $"{nameof(lblAge)}{i}" };
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panChild);
            panChild.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Name = $"lblAge{i}",
                Text = $"Age {ages[i]}",
                Location = new Point(4, 4),
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                Padding = new Padding(2),
                AutoSize = true
            }); ;
            panChild.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Name = $"lblName{i}",
                Text = panNames[i],
                Location = new Point(63, 40),
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Padding = new Padding(2),
                AutoSize = true
            });
#if DEBUG
            // For debug, make it obvious where the label rectangles lie.
            foreach (var label in panChild.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                label.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
#endif
        }
        flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN && Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd) is Control control)
        {
            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ClickAnywhere?.Invoke(control, EventArgs.Empty);
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
    public event EventHandler ClickAnywhere;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @IV. , you are absolutely right, the times the click event was not triggering and thought it was delaying is when I was clicking on the labels mistakenly, thinking I was getting the whole Panel. I should resort to IMessageFilter instead, thank you very much. Be blessed.